# jQuery slideToggle variable duration

Tags: jquery

I have a function where I want the speed of the slideToggle to be dependent on how many children/list items are in the list "`$(this).prevAll('.list_category:first')`". Can someone tell me where I'm being stupid?

```
$(".expand").click(function() {
var iNum = $(this).prevAll('.list_category:first').length();
var tNum = iNum*100;
    $(this).prevAll('.list_category:first').slideToggle(tNum, function(){
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from `length()`:

```
var iNum = $(this).prevAll('.list_category:first').length;
```

Or you can use [`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/)

```
var iNum = $(this).prevAll('.list_category:first').size();
```